# Want to sort an ArrayList of objects by several different attributes

Tags: java, comparable

I've got this class called Block (each Block has an x value and a y value). I've created a bunch of these and put them all in a list. I've managed to sort the list by x-value:

```
public class Block implements Comparable<Block> {
...
public int compareTo(Block block2){
    return this.x - block2.x;
}
```

But I want to be able to sort the list both by x and by y-value at my leisure. Is this doable somehow?

Comment: What is the sort condition when involves both x and y value?

Comment: Use a `Comparator<Block>` instead of the default `compareTo(method)` (and of course the right `sort` method that uses the `Comparator<Block>`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement two [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)s:

```
enum BlockSort implements Comparator<Block> {
    XSORT {
        @Override
        public int compare(Block b1, Block b2) {
            return b1.x - b2.x;
        }
    },

    YSORT {
        @Override
        public int compare(Block b1, Block b2) {
            return b1.y - b2.y;
        }
    }
}
```

Then pass the appropriate instance `XSORT`/`YSORT` as a second argument to the sort method. For example:

```
Collections.sort(blockList, BlockSort.XSORT);
```

Additionally, if by-`x` isn't the *natural ordering* of `Block` instances, it would likely be wiser to not make `Block`s `Comparable` at all.

Comment: Why are there 2 separate `enum`s?

Comment: @JoshM We only will ever need a single instance of `XSort`/`YSort`, so we can make them `enum`s where `INSTANCE` is this single instance. Or are you saying we could put both in a single `enum`?

Comment: I was thinking of a single `enum`. See my answer, although I think JNL beat me to it. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 [Comparators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to achieve this.

```
public class XComparator implements COmparator<Block>{
  public int compare(T o1, T o2){
    ...
  }
}
```

and :

```
public class YComparator implements COmparator<Block>{
  public int compare(T o1, T o2){
    ...
  }
}
```

Then use one of them to sort:

```
Collections.sort(list, new XComparator());
Collections.sort(list, new YComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

Much like @arshajii's answer, you could utilize an `enum` for the various different sorting methods, code shown below:

```
public enum BlockSorting implements Comparator<Block> {
    X{
        public int compare(final Block b1, final Block b2){
            return b1.x - b2.x;
        }
    },
    Y{
        public int compare(final Block b1, final Block b2){
            return b1.y - b2.y;
        }
    };
}
```

The advantage to using this way is that you could easily add more sorting methods (without creating a new `enum` each time). For example, to sort the collection of `Block`s using the X, you could do something like this:

```
Collection<Block> blocks = ....;
Collections.sort(blocks, BlockSorting.X);
```

Comment: I was just updating my answer to use a single `enum`. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with Enums;

```
public static enum Order implements Comparator {
     ByX() {
        public int compare(Block b1, Block b2) {
           return b1.x - b2.x;
        }
     },

     ByY() {
        public int compare(Block b1, Block b2) {
           // TODO: Should really use a collator.
           return b1.y - b2.y;
        }
};
```

Then you call it by,

```
Collections.sort(blocks, Order.ByX);
```